# How can I trigger an event from parent to child component

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to trigger an event from a Parent component to a Child component and I don't find any suitable solution for my case.

My use case is a Parent component which handle save action by displaying buttons or else, and a Child component which need to know when he has to save his data.

The only way which satisfies me is by using RxJS, but I feel it's not a good practice.

I specify that I'm in a context where I try to write an UI library, so I try to simplify and type props as much as possible.

Moreover, my Child component is injected in the Parent component dynamically, so I can't just wrap the Child component with Parent and pass a callback to Parent component.

I thought about two solutions:

1. By using a boolean

My Parent component can handle a boolean and pass it to the Child component. My Child component can react when the boolean changes.

I think it is more a workaround than a real solution.

2. By using a ref

The Parent component explicitly calls a function defined in Child component.

Why not, but I think it's quite ugly. I loose typing, my Child component

Best solution for me using RxJS

If I could use RxJS I would pass an observable from Parent to Child, like this:

```tsx
const Parent = () => {

  const [subject] = useState(() => {
    return new Subject<void>()
  })

  const onSaveClicked = () => {
    subject.next()
  }

  return <>
    <div>
      <button onClick={onSaveClicked}>
        Save something
      </button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <Child saveObservable={subject.asObservable()}/>
    </div>
  </>
}
```

```tsx
const Child = ({saveObservable}: {saveObservable: Observable<void>}) => {

  const [saveCounter, setSaveCounter] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = saveObservable.subscribe({
      next: () => {
        // do someting, save for exemple

        // Here I increment the count to show the event is well handled
        setSaveCounter(x => x + 1)
      }
    })

    return () => subscription.unsubscribe()
  }, [saveObservable]);

  return <>
    Save triggered count: {saveCounter}
  </>
}
```

I don't understand why there is no mechanism already existing which allow me to do that, I feel like I messed something.

Someone can enlighten me ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a *[Context API](https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext)* in react which you can leverage to achieve your requirement. With context, you can pass data down the component tree without passing props manually at every level(*[prop-drilling](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-prop-drilling-in-react)*). You can create a context to handle the save action and consume it in the child component and it also simplifies the component structure and eliminates the need for third-party libraries like `RxJS`. Let me help you with your use-case using this.

1. I would create a custom hook  and a `Provider`.

   ```js
     // SaveCotext.jsx
    import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

     const SaveContext = createContext();

      const useSave = () => useContext(SaveContext);

      const SaveProvider = ({ children }) => {
      const [saveTrigger, setSaveTrigger] = useState(false);

      const triggerSave = () => {
        setSaveTrigger((prev) => !prev);
      };

     return (
       <SaveContext.Provider value={{ saveTrigger, triggerSave }}>
          {children}
       </SaveContext.Provider>
      );
    };

    export { SaveProvider, useSave };
   ```
2. Then would wrap my Parent Component with the `SaveProvider`.

   ```js
   // ... rest of the code
    <SaveProvider>
      <Parent />
    </SaveProvider>
   );
   ```
3. Finally, I would use the save context in Parent and Child components:

   ```js
   const Parent = () => {
   const { triggerSave } = useSave();

   return (
      <div>
       <button onClick={triggerSave}>Save something</button>
       <Child />
     </div>
    );
   };

   const Child = () => {
   const { saveTrigger } = useSave();
   const [saveCounter, setSaveCounter] = useState(0);

   useEffect(() => {
     // Do something, save for example
     setSaveCounter((prev) => prev + 1);
   }, [saveTrigger]);

    return <>Save triggered count: {saveCounter}</>;
   };
   ```

***[SAMPLE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-g9kiy1?file=src%2FApp.js)***

---

##### Note:

1. If you notice in the sample demo I shared initially Save Triggered Count is `1` although the state is initialized with `0`. The reason for it is `setSaveCounter()` is called inside of `useEffect` and on initial render it will trigger the `setSaveCounter()`.
2. In the sample demo I have removed the *[`<StrictMode>`](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode)*. If you're using it(which you should and is strongly recommended in development mode in React `18.x.x`) you will notice the `saveCounter` initializes from `2`. The reason for this can be found ***[here.](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-double-rendering-in-development)***

Answer (score 0):

You can preserve typing with `useRef`, and I think it's probably the way to go with your constraints. You could also use the Context API, but that might reduce the reusability of your component, since you will create a dependency on the context. If the dependency issue is fine for you, then that might be a viable and clean option. Using ref, however, will allow you plug that component in anywhere without having to depend on a shared Context.

Here is an example of that working: https://playcode.io/1744194

```
interface stuffHandler {
  doStuff: () => void;
}

interface childProps {
  prop: string;
}

const Child = React.forwardRef<stuffHandler, childProps>((props, ref) => {
  const refHandler = React.useRef(null)
  const [saveCounter, setSaveCounter] = React.useState(0)

 
  const incrementSave = () => {
    setSaveCounter(saveCounter + 1);
  }
  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      doStuff: incrementSave
    }
  })

  return (<>
    {props.prop}: {saveCounter}
  </>

  )
})

export function Parent() {
  const childRef = React.useRef<stuffHandler>(null)


  const onSaveClicked  = () => {
    childRef.current.doStuff();
  }

  return (
    <>

      <input type="button" onClick={() => onSaveClicked ()} value="Save Something" />
      <Child prop={"TEXT"} ref={childRef} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Declare subject in Parent:**

```
 const [subject] = createSubject();
```

**Declare createSubject outside Parent:**

```
const createSubject = () => {
  const [saveTrigger, setSaveTrigger] = useState(0);

  const next = () => setSaveTrigger(saveTrigger + 1);

  const subscribe = ({ next = () => null }) => {
    if (saveTrigger) {
      // do otherstuff
      next();
    }
    return {
      unsubscribe: () => {
        // doSomthing
      },
    };
  };

  const asObservable = () => {
    return {
      subscribe,
      saveTrigger,
    };
  };

  return [{
      next,
      asObservable,
    }];
};
```

---

Below is the concept, following React [suggestion to avoid useEffect](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#adjusting-some-state-when-a-prop-changes) for React updates.

```
const ParrentComponent = ({ contentToBeSaved }) => {
  const [saveTrigger, setSaveTrigger] = React.useState(0); // or true false

  const onSaveClicked = () => {
    setSaveTrigger(saveTrigger + 1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {/* ...otherComponents */}
      <ChildComponent
        contentToBeSaved={contentToBeSaved}
        saveTrigger={saveTrigger}
      />
    </>
  );
};

const ChildComponent = ({ contentToBeSaved, saveTrigger }) => {
  const [prevSaveTrigger, setPrevSaveTrigger] = React.useState(saveTrigger);

  if (prevSaveTrigger !== saveTrigger) {
    setPrevSaveTrigger(saveTrigger);
    // handle saving
  }
  return <div>Save trigger: {prevSaveTrigger}</div>;
};
```